# generic extends parameter not assignable to argument type

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to use `extends` in a generic parameter to index an object but I'm getting the following error:

> Argument of type 'IHandlerMap[K]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BasicHandler'.
>     Type 'BasicHandler | KeyPressHandler' is not assignable to type 'BasicHandler'.
>       Type 'KeyPressHandler' is not assignable to type 'BasicHandler'.ts(2345)

Code:

```js
export type BasicHandler = () => void;
export type KeyPressHandler = (keyCode: number) => void;

interface IHandlerMap {
  OnTick: BasicHandler;
  OnKeyDown: KeyPressHandler;
}

type HandlersType = {[key in keyof IHandlerMap]: IHandlerMap[key][]};

export class EventManager {
  private readonly handlers: HandlersType = {
    OnTick: [],
    OnKeyDown: [],
  };

  public addHandler<K extends keyof IHandlerMap>(
    type: K,
    handler: IHandlerMap[K]
  ): {
    this.handlers[type].push(handler); // Error is occuring here.
  }
}
```

It appears that TS is only able to deduce that the object property is an array of `BasicHandler` types when it can be `BasicHandler` OR `KeyPressHandler`?

How do I use `keyof` to index an interface (`handler: IHandlerMap[K]`) and then use that parameter to push to a object key that is also `type`'d (`this.handlers[type].push(handler)`?

I'm having a lot of trouble explaining what I'm trying to do, is this the wrong way to go about doing this? If so, what is an alternative?

Comment: Interesting, I dont see any other way than assertion to unsound type like `any` for now. I hope @jcalz will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, the expression type of `this.handlers[type]` triggers your error:

Inside the `addHandler` function body we don't know, which of the two values `"OnTick"` or `"OnKeyDown"` property `type` has, so its base type `keyof IHandlerMap` or `"OnTick" | "OnKeyDown"` is assumed for property access. The Property access `this.handlers[type]` will resolve to the type `HandlersType[keyof IHandlerMap]`, which is `BasicHandler[] | KeyPressHandler[]`.

Now when we invoke `this.handlers[type].push`, the `push` method can be either called with `BasicHandler[]` or `KeyPressHandler[]`, so its type is the *union* of both `push` methods:

```
| (...items: BasicHandler[]): number 
| (...items: KeyPressHandler[]): number
```

Starting with TS 3.3 you *can* actually call a [union type of functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types), but their parameters get *intersected* (`&`). The `push` signature looks rather like this:

```
(method) Array<T>.push(items: (BasicHandler & KeyPressHandler)[]): number
```

`BasicHandler` has no function parameters, `KeyPressHandler` one. So the intersection results in ... no expected parameters. You can add an argument like `s: string` to `BasicHandler` and it gets more apparent (hover over `push` then).

#### What can we do?

Use an extra variable for `this.handlers` with type `HandlersTypeMixed` or use it for `this.handlers` directly. Note: `(BasicHandler | KeyPressHandler)[]` `!==` `BasicHandler[] | KeyPressHandler[]`. Only the former won't result in union function types and allow the `push`. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCBDAzgSwMYASGAdgCYA2wUcAvHABRYBccWMUOxA5gJS0B8cAG4QcpANwBYAFChIsBMlQBpYIgAKUYFixEylanXoBrNQGEIpYC2IBXALYAjKnxqCRYqdJmcYVAGYYeKgAknoUVACyGGBwAN4ycHAA8sQAKvjGLJi4hCQRUF5JqaqIACIQAO7ELKWa2rr5Bl4AvjIySChw4QZYaUq08XAA2qaIcJxwYxD+cGFNUTEAuiz08-qLYKNqSzzDS3AtXh0DPVR9SpE4IMCkg3EjYxPEU2ozc2dQ0WArDDn4nzgAB84HUtDpPnsDm1vLJwNB4HhyNgsHAAKJCYDEGDRYgYLhUeKJOBgDhCDB+OBaDCkCDEcjjAAWCygzG6LIuXToCWkSWK6UyLH2ABpifzShVqkKlqLeYdjnKwLZHOR8HAaaRPgAeZRwUB+Mio6azdYFb78ehixQoWqyvlwZkbKAsU0Gb7DZRLYl8Hn2vB0tgOtmfTnAK43O6DGCMnBYAB0joKWCtjKww06wCWcaVWEZ9ETBh4RT5AHoSwgY-GC+d00oszm89WoEW4GX0VAoNAJqiIHg8LYONwHVRgHHiTCWkA)

```
type HandlersTypeMixed = { [key in keyof IHandlerMap]: (BasicHandler | KeyPressHandler)[] }

public addHandler<K extends keyof IHandlerMap>(
    type: K,
    handler: IHandlerMap[K]
) {
    const hs: HandlersTypeMixed  = this.handlers
    hs[type].push(handler);
}
```

Comment: Marking as answer.

Note for others that might face something similar: Adding an extra variable seems to be the better approach over using it directly, used directly when we call the functions in the handlers arrays we need to typecast the function correctly. By using a extra variable we don't need to worry about typecasting handler functions.